# Google Maps not showing Multiple pins in a single location

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

why is it that when I add multiple pins in a single location only one pin is showing?

[image: Google Map with List of Lat and Long]

My code ( I am using Ionic Framework / AngularJs)

```
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(8.4844173, 124.6526134);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            maxWidth: 185
        });
        var setMarkers = new Array();
        for( var i in data ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lon);

            setMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                content: data[i].description
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(setMarker, 'click', (function (setMarker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent("<div class='card'><div class='item item-body'><a href='#/home/posts/"+data[i].id+"'><img style='width:100%;height100%;' src='http://crowdalert.me/images/"+data[i].image+"'></a></div><div class='item item-divider'><p><i class='ion-clock'></i> "+data[i].created_at+"</p></div></div>");
                    infowindow.open(map, setMarker);
                }
            })(setMarker, i));

            setMarkers.push(setMarker);

        }
```

Comment: Your pins are probably overlapping each other, I guess you should aggregate all the info about the point in one single pin.

Comment: Yes, they are overlapping each other since they do have the same latitude and longitude. I guess I need to use your suggestion. I'm going to add all the info of the same location with a single pin.